# What would be the effects of having no barrier between the conscious and subconscious?

Tags: science-based, humans, psychology, psionics

**A little background...**

I have a story idea revolving around "Agent ROY-G-BIV" (the name is a reference to the 7 colors of the rainbow), a self-propagating form of electromagnetic radiation that is intense enough to edit DNA. However, rather than damaging DNA, it restructures it. Its main effect is on the brain, in that it alters and amplifies the electromagnetic radiation produced naturally by the brain, which causes living creatures it affects to become 'broadcasters': walking radio towers that help to spread Agent ROY-G-BIV.

The thing about agent ROY-G-BIV is that elements of it mirror the brainwaves produced by the subconscious of the 'broadcasters' that aid in propagating it. The end result is that 'broadcasters' that are within close proximity of each other end up receiving brainwaves from the unconscious of fellow 'broadcasters', forming a 'collective subconscious' that can exchange information. Basically, Agent ROY-G-BIV creates a 'wifi network' of sorts out of the 'broadcasters' subconscious.

If you're thinking this is kinda similar to Agent Rainbow from the videogame In Sound Mind then you'd be right.

One other thing Agent ROY-G-BIV does is essentially destroy the barriers between the conscious and subconscious mind, essentially taking away your ability to suppress doubts and other aspects of your psyche. This leads to my question...

**What would be the psychological effects of not being able to suppress dark thoughts or unsavory personality elements?**

Comment: Subconscious and conscious are Freud. It's bad science. We still use the terms because they have some idiomatic use even today, but I don't think moder neurocog science makes such a distinction, or speculates that there is a "barrier" between the two.

Comment: As John O says, if you're going to treat made up pseudoscience as true in your world, it's up to you to make up the rules for that made up pseudoscience. The effects for no barrier will be whatever you want them to be. Since answering this question is entirely up to personal discretion it's not a good fit for this site.

Comment: Ok, corrected some issues with the question. I'm basically asking what would happen if the 'shadow', all the things your psyche tries to suppress and contain, was let loose to wreak psychological havok.

Comment: Technobabble is technobabble, whether it uses Freudian psychanalytical terms, or Jungian psychological archetype terms, or cosmic magical mushrooms as the recent ST:D. People who are unable to "suppress" ($\leftarrow$ technobabble) dark thoughts or "unsavory" personality traits (if that's what "psychological elements" is supposed to mean) can be awesome, can be miserable, can be trailblazers, can be suicidal, can be volatile, can be stoic, can be a joy to work with, can be a pain in the behind, can be adorable, can be insufferable, can be well-adjusted, can be borderline multipolar. Your pick.

Comment: @Brinstar77 Give some examples of what is the "conscious mind"  and what is the "unconscious mind."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Target individuals will quickly turn schizophrenic**

Our conscious and unconscious are divided for a reason - we need the ability to think clearly while all subconscious thinking is being suppressed. It is speculated that in people suffering from schizophrenia this divide is not as firm as in healthy people, and this is why they are hearing "voices" and sometimes are unable to differentiate reality from their imagination.

Comment: A good answer, though I'd also like to know the results of the mind being unable to suppress its shadow (talking in Freudian terms).

Answer (score 2):

To maintain that Freudian distinction, you're asking what happens when the *ego* no longer exists, or functions, at least, as a mediator between the *id* and the *super-ego*.
This will cause psychological struggle, likely expressed outwardly as anxiety or agony, as morals and values clash with basic animalistic instincts.

However, these struggles will eventually come to a halt. Our morals and values, once we reach our teens, are usually pretty defined and rigid, and our basal needs, while instinctual, will occur in patterns or at least be recognisable, leading me to believe this feedback system will reach an equilibrium (until a completely new desire is introduced, which won't happen often and will quickly be assimilated again).

In short: **high amounts of anxiety in ages 4 - 12, and decreasingly rare fits of anxiety after that period.**

Answer (score 1):

1. You will not dream anymore.
2. You will be able to raise or low heart beat and blood pressure at will. This can help a big deal in coping fear, fight bravely.
3. You can sweat more or less at will. This can make people fall in love with you or atleast like you depending on how you smell. Also, you can totally prevent showing any sign of fear, likeness, self doubt, excitement etc.
4. You will probably not laugh at jokes anymore. You may loose sense of humour entirely.
5. You may find hard to understand meaning of idioms and analogies beyond literal meanings of words.
6. You may be able to motivate yourself to do anything. You no longer have to read self-help books.
7. You may find it hard to read. Pictures will make more sense to you.

Comment: This doesn't answer my question. I'm asking about the psychological consequences of the brain no longer being able to maintain a definitive barrier between the conscious and unconscious, causing suppressed thoughts and desires to come to the surface. I'm not asking about the potential physical/psychological pros/cons of having your subconscious subsumed into the conscious.

Comment: I have removed pure physiological parts. The ones that are related to psychology are not removed because I think they are needed. Psychiatrists do treat mentally ill and treatment involves giving medicines so physiology cannot be entirely ignored. Also, its said that a mentally ill cannot understand humour or has his own idea of whats funny so I have kept that part.

Comment: @Atif There are loads of different types of mentally ill people. Some of them understand humor and some of them don't. Some of them make jokes but they are really bad jokes. Some of them make jokes but they are so advanced that they go over the heads of most other people.

Comment: @Daron yes, agreed. Even psychiatrists cannot uniformly or clearly define what is mental illness. A highly intelligent person would look like mentally ill to below averages. This is relevant because when you talk about subconscious you talk about psychiatry. Some who understand normal humour but are labelled as mentally ill may not be mentally ill after all, who knows.

Answer (score 0):

**Become Animalistic**

[image: he throws a baby into the lake]

When the barrier between the two minds breaks down, you lost self-control or discipline.

The unconscious mind regulates some physical systems. It also regulates emotions. It is what makes you angry or sleepy or hungry or sad.

The conscious mind decides what to do with those emotions.

You might be really mad at that foul-mouthed child, but still decide not to throw the child into the ocean. Maybe the first thing you do is phone the child's parents.

You might be really hungry but still decide not to eat the entire birthday cake. Or at least wait until after the birthday song, and everyone gets a slice. Then you hoover up the remains.

You might be really sad due to events. But still have the discipline to pull yourself out of bed in the morning and go to work.

Once the barrier is removed, you no longer have the discipline. You chuck the child into the ocean. You eat the entire cake. You stay in bed all day.

There are no longer "dark thoughts". Those come from suppressing your unconscious urges. But now you are not suppressing them. You are acting on them.